# Acceptance sampling schemes for binomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Two acceptance sampling schemes, A and B, are proposed for deciding whether or not
to accept a large batch of items from a production process in which 5% of the items
produced are defective.
Scheme A: take a random sample of size 20 and accept the batch if no more than 2
defectives are found, otherwise reject it.
Scheme B: take a random sample of size 10; accept the batch if no defectives are found and
reject the batch if 2 or more are present. If 1 defective is found, take a further sample of
size 10, and accept the batch if the number of defectives in this second sample is no more
than 1; otherwise reject the batch.

(a) Find the probability of acceptance for each of the two schemes.

(b) Find the expected number of items sampled for each scheme.

It cost Rs. 10.00 to test each item sampled and for every batch rejected a further cost of
Rs.2000.00 is incurred. Do not consider the cost of testing any replacement batches.

(c) Suggest, giving your reason, which scheme should be adopted.

*here I got some answers for***

(a) For A scheme the probability of acceptance = 0.9245

```
For B scheme the probability of acceptance = 0.8867
```

(b) For A the expected number of items = 18.49

```
For B the expected number of items = 11.747 ( I am not sure about this answer,if I am wrong please correct me)
```

(c) this part is some sort of confusing I require some help from you guys here..

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to find the expected cost of each scheme.

The cost of that scheme now will depend on the cost incurred for each item sampled, and the cost for each batch rejected (sum of both expected costs).

The cost of each item sample in turn depends on the expected number of items sampled under the scheme.

The cost of each rejected batch depends on the acceptance of the scheme.

Comment: sir if possible can you post the answer to check with my answer..

Comment: @RandunuWaitforItPalihakkara Don't call me 'sir' please ^^; Also, I'd rather you post the workings you've got so far through an edit of your question and let me know when you have put it there to have a look.

Comment: (c) for A cost = Rs.184.90 and for B cost = Rs.262.89 hence economically viable method is A

Comment: @RandunuWaitforItPalihakkara Could you show your workings for part (a) scheme B? P(acceptance on first sampling) = 0.95^10 = 0.5987, which is already higher than the answer you got.

Comment: i made a mistake for that B it should be 0.8867

Comment: @RandunuWaitforItPalihakkara Yup. Now for the part (b), note that for scheme A, you will be sampling 20 items, no matter how many defects there are.

Comment: yeah sure,
cost for B = 10(0.05)(.95)^9 {.95^10+10*.05*.95^9{10*20+2000}   =Rs. 693.43 is this the correct answer??

Comment: @RandunuWaitforItPalihakkara Not really. What did you get for Part (b) expected sample items for scheme B? 5.65 is not good, since at least 10 items will be sampled.

Comment: expected no of items for scheme B = 11.747

Comment: @RandunuWaitforItPalihakkara Could you include your workings please? There's something off.

Comment: expected no of items for 
scheme B= 10*.95^10+20{(10*.05*.95^9)*(.95^10+10*.05*.95^9)}=11.747

Comment: @RandunuWaitforItPalihakkara: $\text{Expectation for sample in Scheme B} = np$. You can have two scenarios: n = 10 and n = 20. You need to find the probability of each occurring. When does n = 10? When does n = 20?